# Why the first value in step json array returned by Google directions api is not consistent with other items in the step list?

Tags: json, google-directory-api

Below is a Json response from Google-directions-api.

If we look at distance object **value seems to be in meters** and **text is round off value in kilometer**. But the first object doesn't follow this.

Similar is the case with duration. Value is in seconds and text is round off value in minutes. **But the first object in the steps array is not consistent with the result.**

I need a consistent data for my Application. What is wrong with this? Is there any solution?

**Note:** Not all responses are inconsistent but for some responses inconsistency is there.

Any Kind of suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
"steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "20 m",
                        "value" : 20
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 6
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 25.5940352,
                        "lng" : 85.1373598
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003ewest\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "uye{CwlsfOAf@"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 25.5940333,
                        "lng" : 85.1375638
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.1 km",
                        "value" : 124
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 65
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 25.5944879,
                        "lng" : 85.1365761
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eright\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eBangali Tola Bus Stand Rd\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eMithapur Bus Stand Rd\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003ePatna - Aurangabad Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-right",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "wye{CoksfOI?i@AM?GAA@A??@A@Ah@?DGhB"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 25.5940352,
                        "lng" : 85.1373598
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "1.1 km",
                        "value" : 1096
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "5 mins",
                        "value" : 325
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 25.5849493,
                        "lng" : 85.1338281
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eBangali Tola Bus Stand Rd\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003eMithapur Bus Stand Rd\u003c/b\u003e/\u003cb\u003ePatna - Aurangabad Rd\u003c/b\u003e\u003cdiv style=\"font-size:0.9em\"\u003eContinue to follow Mithapur Bus Stand Rd/Patna - Aurangabad Rd\u003c/div\u003e",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "q|e{CsfsfObBXxB`@tATD@p@Lv@LbEr@XDx@NhB\\~Dv@~@Np@LbDv@rDz@ZFjGpAbBXv@N"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 25.5944879,
                        "lng" : 85.1365761
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },]
```

Comment: What is the inconsistency? `20 m` vs `0.1 km`? If that's it, then dividing `value` by 1000 might work?

Comment: look at first object and duration text is 1 min and value is 6. But consistency should give us value close to 60.

Comment: Believe in google and look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully, there is no inconsistency.

**First Object:**

`distance:`  Value is in meters. value = 20 meter and hence text is `20 m`

`duration:`  Value is in seconds. value = 6 seconds = 0.1 minutes. Rounding it off to non-zero integer value gives 1 minute and hence the text is `1 min`

Other objects follow the same pattern.

Cheers!